# Remove WorkFlow from List Instance

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, visual-studio

I have Created one Document Library Definition.I have Created two Document Library Instance  from that Definition.I had created one workflow.I want to associate workflow for only one Document Library Instance Is it possible to do that.I want to do it pragmatically from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Following links might be help

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nishand/archive/2008/08/27/how-to-add-remove-and-start-workflow-programmatically.aspx

http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/09/how-to-attach-workflow-to-list-from.html